# What's the difference between "uname -r" and "uname -v"?

Tags: linux, unix, centos, manpages

I am using CentOS 6.2. In the man page of uname (i.e., `man uname`), it says:

```
 -r, --kernel-release
              print the kernel release

 -v, --kernel-version
              print the kernel version
```

While trying the command, it shows

```
[max@localhost ~]$ uname -r

2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.i686

[max@localhost ~]$ uname -v

#1 SMP Tue May 15 22:09:39 BST 2012
```

`-v` should show the version, right? But where is it showing the version? `-r` is showing the version detail.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 9):

This is absolutely normal and expected. `kernel-release` will always show the actual version number of the used kernel. `kernel-version` however will print a more specific string with the actual release date. Its format depends on which Linux or Unix distribution it's run on.

---

You can find an extensive [list of examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname#Examples) on Wikipedia. For example, in OS X, the `kernel-version` will be not only the release number, but also the release date:

```
Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

While the `kernel-release` is simply the release number:

```
10.8.0
```

You can even check `/proc/sys/kernel/` for the things `uname(2)` will look up when it's called by `uname(1)`. This would be:

- `/proc/sys/kernel/version`
- `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease`

Don't think too strictly of "version" as just a version *number*.

Comment: Obviously the right answer, whether the other poster disagrees or not.